# Airflow UI loading extremely slow after upgrading version

Tags: airflow

I upgraded my airflow cluster from 1.7.1.3 to 1.10.1. After the upgradation the main page UI of airflow is loading very slowly. I tried reducing the page size and increasing the workers for the webserver but that didn't help. I am using the following configs -

```
page_size = 15
workers = 4
web_server_master_timeout = 120
web_server_worker_timeout = 120
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5
```

Can someone help me with what is happening here?

Comment: did you find out why it was slow? I'm running into a similar problem where tasks execute slowly, the UI page is slow. `airflow list_dags -r` takes 15 minutes!

Comment: @Seth The command list_dags for me runs quickly. To tackle the slowness of the UI I reduced the page size further to 10 and increased the workers to 8 as i am using 8 core machine. Its running faster than before.

Comment: I appreciate that ,so having more workers increased the speed of the tasks, etc?

Comment: some of the solutions to improve the web UI speed mentioned here - https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/8907